# LeafletJS Popup work without openPopup

Tags: popup, leaflet, mapbox, markers

I'm using a JSON file to get the data and creating markers with it.I'm binding a popup to the marker.Now the bizarre thing is the popup will open once the marker is clicked.There isn't any method that says marker.openPopup() in the entire file.If If I include that method in an onclick function it won't open at all. Does anybody know what the problem could be?

Comment: If you are using `.bindPopup()` to bind a popup, then it's not at all bizarre that the popup would open when the marker is clicked. That is actually the intended behavior (`.bindPopup` attaches the listeners for you). As to why it would *not* open when you try to use your own event listener, you will need to include some example code illustrating the problem before we can offer any help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure to provide enough info and code so that people can reproduce your issue and provide you some support. As for your click not opening your popup, I suspect it might be due to your click propagating to the map, therefore closing the popup right away.

Comment: i agree with @ghybs. Without context, your question cannot be answered. openPopup() needs to be called on the right layer: see http://plnkr.co/edit/ebdjrFVxlf38kyKlqLOA?p=preview